# Separar un texto por IFrames en PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy intentando separar un texto `HTML` que contiene `iframes` a partir de un `preg_split`, y no me sale. Lo que necesito es crear un `array` con textos e `iframes`. Por ejemplo `['texto', 'iframe', 'iframe', 'texo']`.

Lo que he hecho ha sido esto:

```
<?
php 
    $html = '<span style="font-size:14px;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" mozallowfullscreen="" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/34234234" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="640"></iframe></span></p>
        <p>
            <span style="font-size:14px;"><a href="https://vimeo.com/34234234"> Texto.</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/user7990284">Texto</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</span></p>
        <p>';

    $separacionIframes = preg_split('/(<iframe[^>]+>)/i', $html, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    print_r($separacionIframes);
?>
```

Lo que me pinta es un `array` pero de esta forma: 
`['texto', 'iframe + texto']` y tendría que ser `['texto', 'iframe', 'texto]`.

No sé si me he explicado bien, cualquier duda que tengáis preguntádmela. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola CSC99, no está muy claro. Te sugiero que pulses en [edit] para añadir ejemplos **exactos** de lo que intentas separar y el resultado final , asi como lo que estas obteniendo ahora mismo. Mira [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Parece que funciona tal como esperas: mira: https://ideone.com/9ye5cv No sé si el problema es que te gustaría que el cierre de etiqueta de iframe quedase en la posición 2 en lugar de la tercera. Es eso? Podrías utilizar `/(<iframe[^>]*>.*?</iframe>)/is` en tal caso

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente: `preg_split("/(<iframe[^>]*>.*?<\/iframe>)/is", $html, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Demo: https://ideone.com/1pHmrN

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <span style="font-size:14px;">
    [1] => <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" mozallowfullscreen="" src="https://p...content-available-to-author-only...o.com/video/34234234" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="640"></iframe>
    [2] => </span></p>
        <p>
            <span style="font-size:14px;"><a href="https://v...content-available-to-author-only...o.com/34234234"> Texto.</a> from <a href="https://v...content-available-to-author-only...o.com/user7990284">Texto</a> on <a href="https://v...content-available-to-author-only...o.com">Vimeo</a>.</span></p>
        <p>
)
```